# How can I read a protoBuffer .pb file in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, protocol-buffers, pyspark, proto

Suppose I have a protoBuffer file sampleFile.pb which has some serialized text in it, but now I want to read it in pySpark dataframe. I can use google.protobuf to read back that file and de-serialize it but data is very huge so I want to read and perform transformations on that data in parallel distributed fashion. I have gone through many blogs but no luck. Please give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**addressbook.proto**

```
syntax = "proto2";

package tutorial;

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

**Generated SampleFile.pb file through addressbook_pb2:**

```
@
Bilalõbilal@gmail.com"  
1112222"
2223333"
3334444
```

So its just simple data, a sample example provided in google protobuff page.

Comment: Many of the protobuf implementations expose a raw reader API that can be used for this kind of purpose if you want to avoid the usual materialisation loop. How complex is the schema here? Do you have the .proto schema available?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have edited and updated the question with proto file and protobuff .pb data. Its has really simple data structure. Please guide.

Comment: question: what language/framework are you using here? pySpart makes me think "python" - would https://pypi.org/project/pystream-protobuf/ be any use?

Comment: @MarcGravell right it can be used but idea is to read .pb file into a pyspark dataframe for distributed reading.

Comment: You can not do this natively with Spark as it does not provide a reader for the `pb` format. You can read it as a text file into RDD and use the existing libraries as the one pointed by @MarcGravell to convert to JSON RDD so that you can create your Dataframe.

Comment: @blackbishop right, so what i did is, I used Scalapb to generate protobuf message files and then read it back into a Dataframe using scalapb. Scalapb it self first read the whole encoded file as text file: **val persons: RDD[Person] = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(parseLine)**. So is reading of a text file into an RDD distributed? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by blackbishop, there is no native spark reader available for reading protobuf files, So I used ScalaPB open source project to achieve this. ScalaPB read whole file as a text file and then perform serialization after that it can be converted into a dataframe.

```
https://scalapb.github.io/
```